# JavaFX LocalTime to build a Stopwatch

Tags: javafx, localtime

The code below was used to build a stopwatch the variable sMIN and sSEC are set when a button is pressed and the method is called from an AnimationTimer

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to write this routine as it seems to be spaghetti like code

```
    private void elapsedTIME(){

    eSEC = LocalTime.now().getSecond();

    if(eSEC > sSEC){
        showSEC = eSEC - sSEC;
    }
    if(eSEC <= sSEC){
        showSEC = eSEC + (60-sSEC);     
    }

    if(showSEC == 60 && elapsedTimeTest == true){
        elapsedTimeTest = false;
    }
    if(showSEC == 60 && elapsedTimeTest == false ){
        eMIN = LocalTime.now().getMinute();
        if(eMIN > sMIN){
            showMIN = eMIN - sMIN;
        }
        if(eMIN == 0 && eMIN != sMIN){
            showMIN = 60 - sMIN;
        }
        if(eMIN < sMIN && eMIN != 0){
            showMIN = (60-sMIN) + eMIN;
        }
    }
    msg.setText("Elapsed Time "+showMIN+" Minutes "+(showSEC)+" Seconds"); 
}
```

Comment: This kind of question also works well for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, though [it is also fine here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `sSEC` and `sMIN` are the seconds and minutes at the start.

Instead of storing those separately, just store the `LocalTime` at the start. Then you can do something like:

```
LocalTime startTime ;

// ...

private void elapsedTIME(){

    // Assumes startTime is set somewhere before this is invoked

    long elapsedSeconds = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now()).getSeconds();
    long minutes = elapsedSeconds / 60 ;
    long seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60 ;
    msg.setText("Elapsed Time "+minutes+" Minutes "+seconds+" Seconds"); 
}
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Stopwatch extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label stopwatch = new Label();
        BooleanProperty running = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            private LocalTime startTime ;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                long elapsedSeconds = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now()).getSeconds();
                long minutes = elapsedSeconds / 60 ;
                long seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60 ;
                stopwatch.setText("Time: "+minutes +" minutes "+seconds + " seconds");
            }
            @Override
            public void start() {
                running.set(true);
                startTime = LocalTime.now();
                super.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void stop() {
                running.set(false);
                super.stop();
            }
        };

        Button startStop = new Button();
        startStop.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(running).then("Stop").otherwise("Start"));
        startStop.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (running.get()) {
                timer.stop();
            } else {
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, stopwatch, startStop);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(24));
        root.setMinWidth(240);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note this might not quite work correctly if the time passes midnight while the stopwatch is running; you can use `LocalDateTime` instead to fix this problem.

Comment: your code is elegant but if you start the stopwatch at say 59 min and when it goes through the cycle where the min is 00 then the variable min becomes -56 My thought is that we still need a test for when this happens the min can only have two conditions 0 or > 0 hence my test for zero in my code for show min I will try LocalDateTime but not sure that will solve the issue thanks for the help

Comment: use the first version, not the second. (Or keep track of the hours too. )